# Show/hide jQuery function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to code a simple show/hide div using jQuery. Basically, when I click on `.artist-ken`, I want the `artists-home` div to disappear and `.ken-gallery` to replace it.

So far, I have this, but it's not doing anything except jumping to the top of the page:

```
$('.artist-ken').click(function(){
    $('.artists-home').hide().show('ken-gallery');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.artist-ken').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.artists-home').hide();
    $('.ken-gallery').show();
});
```

Function `preventDefault()` will stop from jumping in the page. You need separate `show` for displaying another div. Also `.` was missing in the `ken-gallery`.

Comment: Thank you. I decided that I wanted the divs to fade in and fade out. So I replaced `.hide` with `.fadeOut` and `.show` with `.fadeIn`. It seems to be working. Is there anything else I need to add or is there a more elegant way to write it?

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.show()` doesn't take a selector as a first parameter, try this instead:

```
$('.artist-ken').click(function(){
    $('.artists-home').hide();
    $('.ken-gallery').show();
});
```

I'm assuming that the element that you want to hide has the class ".ken-gallery" and that the element that you want to show has the class: ".artists-home"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.artist-ken').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".artists-home").hide( 0, function() {
        $('.ken-gallery').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the point of having a callback function? There isn't going to be any animation anyway.

Comment: Simple way to ensure the div only shows when the other is hidden.

Comment: Since `hide` is applied instantly, the browser will redraw the computed differences in the same frame. There is no reason to waste more computational power to create another function (though it's very cheap.)

Comment: `e` is most-likely `undefined` in this code. I think you meant to have the `e` argument in the callback function arguments? Also, an explanation of why this works would improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: If you are worried about computational power or anything of that sort then why are you using jQuery in the first place LMAO

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.artist-ken').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.artists-home').hide();
   $('.ken-gallery').show();
});
```

What you did was not a real parameter for the `show()` function. Plus even if it were you didn't specify that it was a class. It can only take a function, duration, nothing, or object refer to the **[jQuery show  reference page](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**  You can also create a one way listener to `show` or `hide` the other.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   if( e.target.classList.contains('artists-home') ) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(e.target).hide();
       $('.ken-gallery').show();
    }else if( e.target.classList.contains('ken-gallery') ){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(e.target).hide();
       $('.artists-home').show();
    }
});
```

Also what Chonger was saying, is if you wanted a fade `which is the duration parameter` for any of the show/hide and other animated properties of jQuery, then we would use a callback. So my single function listener would then become.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   if( e.target.classList.contains('artists-home') ) {
       $(e.target).hide(500,function(){
       $('.ken-gallery').show();
       });
    }else if( e.target.classList.contains('ken-gallery') ){
      $(e.target).hide(500,function(){
       $('.artists-home').show();
       });
    }
});
```

**EDIT** 
  Reread your question, these must be links for the page to jump to top so I added to the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Dude `show()` cant have parameter in () Brackets except Speed Or way of animation like show('slow') OR show('1000') is only valid .

Your syntax is wrong

The following is valid syntax.
It means , hide div with class ".artists-home" and show with class ".ken-gallery".

```
$('.artist-ken').click(function(){
    $('.artists-home').hide();
    $('.ken-gallery').show();
});
```

For more info [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)